# Why is .NET MAUI crashing upon an event handler being activated?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, maui

I am having a strange issue with my .NET MAUI app connected to an API controller and SQL backend. The app successfully accesses the login endpoint of my API and denotes that it logs in (I've confirmed by looking at my SQL db as well as by using Postman). However, once I hit the "login" button on my login page and I am notified that I have logged in, I thereafter call (within the same button event handler) absolute navigation to the home page using

await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(HomePage)}");

I use absolute shell navigation many other places in my app without issue (though to different pages), but for some reason, on this page, hitting "login" crashes my app immediately. Despite no exception being thrown or error, I have deduced that it is this line doing something wrong... and the app works fine if I remove this line. HomePage is a brand new page and I did register its route in appshell. I am flabergasted and would appreciate you input!

I expect to be able to use absolute shell navigation using .NET MAUI without my app crashing.

Comment: Not necessarily an answer, but might help you get closer to your problem.  Put a breakpoint on that `await Shell...` line that you suspect is the problem.  Run your app up until there, and then before continuing, in VS, open the Exception Settings panel (CTRL+ALT+E) and click the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" box until it's a check mark (not a solid box), then continue debugging your app.  With any luck the debugger should break on the *actual* error causing your problem.

Comment: Show us your App class, as well as your AppShell class. "Something wrong happens in my login", without much code to see wont help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(HomePage)}");` in the button clicked event will not crash the app, unless you didn't register the Login Page in the AppShell. In other words, the code in your App.cs is such as:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
      public App()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new LoginPage();
           // MainPage = new AppShell();
      }
}
```

If so, you can register the LoginPage in the shell and use `MainPage = new AppShell()`. Or you can try to change `Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(HomePage)}");` in the button clicked event as `App.Current.MainPage = new AppShell()`.

In addition, if I'm wrong, could you please show more code about the Button click event and the shell?

Comment: thanks for answering and for your help! In my relentless diatribe against this problem, it turns out that my blood-shot-eyes, sleep-deprived, motivated self somehow circumvented registering the route which was causing my app to crash. Unbelievable how much time I spent looking into this problem. Thank you so much for your help, everybody! I apologize. This answer was correct, as well as the debugging help!